# Creating an object with an array as a parameter in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, variables, object

Ok I'm really new to this and am not even sure I'm asking the right question but I want to create an object that has some regualr values like strings and ints etc. But in addition I want one of the properties to be an array of strings like this:

```
int hp =100;
int level =1;
int exp=0;
String[] items = {"hpPot","blank","blank","blank","blank"};
return new player(level, exp, hp, name, items[] );
}
```

This doesn't work and at the least I'd like to know exactly why.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your whole class `player`..?

Comment: Sidenote: why do you add `"blank"` to the items? Unless there's an actual item called "blank", I suggest you don't do this. *Either* pass in `null` for "empty" slots or (probably better) simply pass in an array of just a single element. The actual allocation of storage and checking of the maximum number of items should *probably* belong to the `player` class (which should be named ´Player` in accordance to the generally accepted [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367)).

Comment: Like I said I'm very new blank was merely going to be an object without any values. ty.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer about the naming convention I usally keep the first word lowercase and then do CamelCase from there is that incorrect? Like "variableName" or "variable" or "variableNameHere"

Comment: @Suavelizard: it's correct for *variables* it's **wrong** for class names: It should be `Player player = new Player()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

while passing `array` don't use `subscript operator`

```
return new player(level, exp, hp, name, items); // [] is removed.
```

Comment: I tried this before but it didn't work. I have tweaked some parts of the player class since and now I dont seem to have a problem thanks so much :P

Comment: @TheEliteGentleman: That's what keeps me encouraged to refer to stackoverflow. The appreciation you get in return is HUUUUGE.

Comment: well when you're banging your head against the wall you are grateful for people who give you a helmet, or move you to a padded room :P